# Here iOS SDK Provides Indoor Routing?

Tags: here-api

Is the Here iOS SDK capable of providing indoor routing information? For example, say the venue is a floor in an office building, and I want the iOS app to display a route from the reception area to the restroom. Is that possible? I tried searching through the docs, but not sure I could find anything regarding indoor routing (https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/routing/topics/quick-start.html)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible. Check [NMAVenue3dRoutingController](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/ios-hybrid-plus/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/interfacenmavenue3droutingcontroller.html) in Venue 3D API.
You need to use NMAVenue3dLevelLocation or NMAVenue3dSpaceLocation to define start and end point. Then you can use [NMAVenue3dRoutingController calculateRouteFrom: to:withParams:] method to calculate indoor route.

You can also check [Indoor Venue Routing](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/ios-hybrid-plus/topics/maps-venue-3d-indoor-routing.html) section in HERE iOS SDK Developer's Guide.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do I need to provide Here with details of the floor plan? Otherwise, how does it know how to avoid walls inside a building? Is there a sample app I can download?

Comment: Not sure what exactly do you want to achieve. Do you want to use your custom venue, some local office? Currently there is only examples for [Android](https://github.com/heremaps/here-android-sdk-examples/tree/master/3d-venues-and-indoor-routing).

Comment: We want to provide indoor navigation to our own custom office space (i.e. going from reception to the meeting room).

Comment: To have your own office, you need to use private venues feature (available in Premium license). Also it requires a venue model to be produced by HERE data creating team. It only possible if you make a business agreement with HERE company. First step would be to contact a [sales team](https://developer.here.com/contact-us).

Comment: Got it. Does HERE offer any public venue models we can work with? Is there a catalogue of locations?

Comment: Yes, there is 12000 public venues. Check NMAVenue3dService on iOS or VenueService on Android. You can get there a full list of awailible venues by getting venues for world geo bounding box, for example.